# Query.copyToDataTable not working vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hi guys I am using Linq and trying to copy the result to a table object. However, I am receiving a cast exception.

Here is the code:

```
Dim teams As DataTable = citySideDataset.Tables("Teams")
        Dim query = From team In teams.AsEnumerable() Where team.Field(Of String)("Venue ID") = venueID And team.Field(Of Integer)("Division ID") = divisionID Select team
        Dim boundTable As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable()
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Sorry.
It is a InvalidCastException.

It works all fine until it tries to copy to the dataTable

Comment: Post the exact stack trace or cast exception text. We have NO idea what exception you've got.

Comment: It works until the CopyToDataTable because it isn't *doing* anything until that call. It's all deferred until then. Anyway, check your types. InvalidCastExceptions are fairly straightforward.

Comment: More clearly, look at the table value Venue ID and the corresponding variable and also Division ID and the other variable. One of those types isn't what you expect it to be. The program is trying to cast and it is not successful, hence the error.

Comment: I was following the MSDN website. I checked the database. The Venue ID is a string and the Division ID a number(Long)

Comment: Does Division ID support nulls?

Comment: as a foreign key of the Teams Table yes

Comment: It only says InvalidCastException was unhandled. Specified cast is not valid

Comment: Definefly the problem is on the Division ID field. I removed and it is working. Could suggest anything?

Answer (score 0):

With some exploration in the comments, we learned that your datatype for `Division ID` at the database is a `long`. Your query uses `of Integer` when trying to extract the value from the field, and that is going to throw an error. We also learned that your column supports nulls. To fix your query, you should use `of Nullable(of Long)`, which would make it the following

```
Dim query = From team In teams.AsEnumerable() _
            Where team.Field(Of String)("Venue ID") = venueID _
            And team.Field(Of Nullable(of Long))("Division ID") = divisionID _
            Select team
```

One last consideration that you should be aware of is that `CopyToDataTable()` *will throw* its own exception if no rows pass whatever filters you use. So if there is a chance for your result to be empty, you will want to check for rows prior to invoking that method.

```
Dim boundTable As DataTable
If query.Any() Then
    boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable()
Else
    'just use empty clone of original table, if applicable
    boundTable = table.Clone() 
End If
```

Comment: I tried and it is not working. Definitely it is something related to the number type. I am trying to convert the numbers to Long but it is not working

Comment: Then I return to one of my earliest comments. Something is not the type you expect it to be. Double check the database. Then double check whatever code is producing your original `citySideDataset`, which could indeed be a stored procedure or maybe it's being built in code. Is something turning that column into strings? Decimals? Some other type? That's what you need to find.

Comment: To troubleshoot, step through the code. Put a break point in place where you have the table. Take a look at its columns. You can look at its properties. For example, you could look at teams.Columns("Division ID").DataType. What does it say?